# Connection string from rider to mircorsoft sql server on ubuntu

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ubuntu, connection-string, rider

I install Jetbrains Rider and Microsoft Sql Server 2017 on ubuntu to open an existing ASP.NET project. After a lot of fixes and changes, I was able to run the project properly. But I got the error `SQL Server does not exist or access denied`. I can connect with Datagrip and there is no problem. I just need the exact connection string to connect from Rider to ubuntu Sql server.

Datagrip connection url (successful connection):

`jdbc:sqlserver://myserver\MSSQLSERVER:1433;database=mydb`

Tested and failed connection strings:

`Data Source=myserver\\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;`

`Data Source=myserver\\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=sa;Password=myPassword;`

`Server=myserver\\MSSQLSERVER:1433;database=mydb;User ID=SA;Password=mypass;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the correct one with help of [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/302#issuecomment-315800123) comment.

Something that I shouldn't do was to exclude `MSSQLSERVER` from data source part.

The working connection string is:

`Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=False;User ID=SA;Password=mypass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;`